# Riak "error":"insufficient_vnodes_available"

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, riak

We have 4 nodes Riak installation. They are running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise installed servers. 
We have installed 1.1.4 at August 1st 2012 and upgraded 1.2.0 when its available.

Server names are:

f1 - 10.10.0.12 - This is the first installed server. We have joined other ones to this server. This also serves Riak control.
s2 - 10.10.0.22 -
s3 - 10.10.0.23 -
s4 - 10.10.0.24 - This server also serves Riak control.

This morning we've seen "insufficient nodes available" error at our applications log and restarted all nodes. 3 of them became available except "f1"

> UPDATE : while I prepare this message live 3 nodes became unavailable
>   and need restart Riak.

```
wolfiem@f01:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/riak start
Riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
see the output of 'riak console' for more information.
If you want to wait longer, set the environment variable
WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait.
```

I've tried to set WAIT_FOR_ERLANG value to 60 seconds but I can't.

adding this line in vm.args didn't work:

```
-env WAIT_FOR_ERLANG 60
```

I also tried to set this from terminal but it didn't work either.

```
wolfiem@f01:~$ export WAIT_FOR_ERLANG=60
```

It still says "Riak failed to start within 15 seconds"

This is the console.log output:

```
2012-09-11 10:58:02.532 [info] <0.7.0> Application lager started on node 'riak@10.10.0.12'
2012-09-11 10:58:02.560 [warning] <0.148.0>@riak_core_ring_manager:reload_ring:231 No ring file available.
2012-09-11 10:58:02.585 [error] <0.164.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.164.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: eaddrnotavail in gen_server:init_it/6 line 320
```

This is the error.log output

```
2012-09-11 10:58:02.585 [error] <0.164.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.164.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: eaddrnotavail in gen_server:init_it/6 line 320
```

This is the crash.log output:

```
2012-09-11 10:58:02 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: mochiweb_socket_server:init/1
    pid: <0.164.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {eaddrnotavail,[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,320}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}
    ancestors: [riak_core_sup,<0.135.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.136.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 377
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 403
  neighbours:
```

You can find the riak console output below:

```
wolfiem@f01:~$ riak console
Attempting to restart script through sudo -H -u riak
Exec: /usr/lib/riak/erts-5.9.1/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/lib/riak/releases/1.2.0/riak             -embedded -config /etc/riak/app.config             -pa /usr/lib/riak/basho-patches             -args_file /etc/riak/vm.args -- console
Root: /usr/lib/riak
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true]


=INFO REPORT==== 11-Sep-2012::10:44:18 ===
    alarm_handler: {set,{system_memory_high_watermark,[]}}
** /usr/lib/riak/lib/observer-1.1/ebin/etop_txt.beam hides /usr/lib/riak/lib/basho-patches/etop_txt.beam
** Found 1 name clashes in code paths 
10:44:19.099 [info] Application lager started on node 'riak@10.10.0.12'
10:44:19.130 [warning] No ring file available.
10:44:19.158 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.164.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: eaddrnotavail in gen_server:init_it/6 line 320
/usr/lib/riak/lib/os_mon-2.2.9/priv/bin/memsup: Erlang has closed. 

=INFO REPORT==== 11-Sep-2012::10:44:19 ===
    alarm_handler: {clear,system_memory_high_watermark}
Erlang has closed
                 {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,riak_core,{shutdown,{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: /var/log/riak/erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,riak_core,{shutdown,{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:
http://smartcloud.blogspot.hu/2013/01/setting-riak-cluster-in-amazon-ec2-just.html
it says that the `with 0 neighbours exited with reason` error is due to an (at least partially) running riak instance, that sits on some port or other resource.

For me, it was an epmd instance that ran, i found it with `ps ax |grep riak`. After killing it, the problem went away.